# InappBilling Error- authentication is required. you need to sign into your google account

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I am trying to make a demo of inappbilling. I followed this [tutorial](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Integrating_Google_Play_In-app_Billing_into_an_Android_Application_%E2%80%93_A_Tutorial) for studying this.

Lemme tell the steps I followed for doing this task

1. I used the below mentioned code

   ```
   package com.ohn.inappbilling;

   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
   import android.util.Log;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.widget.Button;

   import com.hello.inappbilling.util.IabHelper;
   import com.hello.inappbilling.util.IabResult;
   import com.hello.inappbilling.util.Inventory;
   import com.hello.inappbilling.util.Purchase;
   import com.ohn.inappbilling.R;

   public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

   private static final String TAG = "com.hello.inappbilling";
   static final String ITEM_SKU = "com.buttonclick";
   IabHelper mHelper;
   private Button clickButton;
   private Button buyButton;


   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       buyButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buyButton);
       clickButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clickButton);
       clickButton.setEnabled(false);
       String base64EncodedPublicKey = "******";

       mHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);

       mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
           public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
               if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                   Log.d(TAG, "In-app Billing setup failed: " + result);
               } else {
                   Log.d(TAG, "In-app Billing is set up OK");
               }
           }
       });
       //throw new RuntimeException();
   }

   public void buttonClicked(View view) {
       clickButton.setEnabled(false);
       buyButton.setEnabled(true);
   }

   public void buyClick(View view) {
        mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, ITEM_SKU, 10001,   
              mPurchaseFinishedListener, "mypurchasetoken");
   }

   @Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, 
        Intent data) 
   {
         if (!mHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode, 
                 resultCode, data)) {     
           super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
         }
   }

   IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener 
   = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
   public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, 
                   Purchase purchase) 
   {
      if (result.isFailure()) {
         // Handle error
         return;
    }      
    else if (purchase.getSku().equals(ITEM_SKU)) {
        consumeItem();
       buyButton.setEnabled(false);
   }

   }


   };

   public void consumeItem() {
       mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mReceivedInventoryListener);
   }

   IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mReceivedInventoryListener 
      = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
          public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result,
             Inventory inventory) {


             if (result.isFailure()) {
             // Handle failure
             } else {
                    mHelper.consumeAsync(inventory.getPurchase(ITEM_SKU), 
               mConsumeFinishedListener);
             }
       }
   };

   IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener mConsumeFinishedListener =
   new IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener() {
    public void onConsumeFinished(Purchase purchase, 
          IabResult result) {

   if (result.isSuccess()) {                
         clickButton.setEnabled(true);
   } else {
          // handle error
   }
   }
   };

   @Override
   public void onDestroy() {
       super.onDestroy();
       if (mHelper != null) mHelper.dispose();
       mHelper = null;
   }

   }
   ```
2. I created apk using *File-Export-AndroidProject* and uploaded this in alphatesting.
3. I added users(Google group) in *Manage list of testers* in alpha testing.
4. I added the product in In-app Product and give id to it *com.buttonclick*
5. In settings in *Gmail accounts with testing* access I added Gmail id's here also. None of the id is developer id.

Can anyone tell solution for this problem. I have tried all the solutions available on `StackoverFlow`.

Comment: Don't know if it's related but I have never could test the IAB without the main/first account set as a tester, I had to reset the device and set the tester account as the main account of the device.

Comment: means you want to say, i delete all accounts from phone, n then add a single account for testing, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution for this problem.

***I published this apk on playstore and then I downloaded apk from playstore and ran that and It worked fine***

I think the reason behind this problem is 
***The google account that I was using for testing may be it was not the main account.***

Comment: Can you explain what you would say with main account? The play store's one? Let's say I've published the alpha with my company's account, info@company.com, and I download it with my personal account me@gmail.com (that's registered in licensed test user list on dev console). Well, I'm getting that error. Do you have any suggestion? Thanks ^^

Answer (score 0):

I spent almost 2 weeks trying to fix this, and I was so frustrated when I realized I didn't actually enable the beta testing:

[image]

**To enable it make sure you actually check the box next to the list name.**